# Windows 2008 R2 VPN. How do I issue IPs based on username?

Tags: routing, windows-server-2008-r2

I have 2 subnets that my VPN server has access to. I want to set it up do that if one username gets access to one subnet and another user gets access to a separate subnet? Can this be done with one server?

Thansk

Comment: More information is required.  What software are you using to run the VPN server?

Comment: I am using L2TP via Routing and Remote Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign static IP address using Active Directory Users and Computers - see the following Knowledge Base article (it does not list Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2008 R2 but the article does apply).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786213(v=WS.10).aspx